# Why do borders have different colors in different sides?

Tags: winapi, colors, border

I found that the left and top border color is grey (160, 160, 160), but the bottom and right border color is white, when I use WS_EX_STATICEDGE.

Can we make the whole edge to be of color grey? (using pure winapi)

Comment: Whata bout the rest of the border? Most are 2+ pixels wide, you'll most likley find that it's bevelled for the 3D effect, and in turn have different colours in different bits.

Answer (score 3):

The border is painted by operating system and there are no implications as for the edge to be painted with solid color. Instead it is current theme, which is applied and being used for painting.

Answering your question directly, yes you can make it. You can take over non-client area painting in your window and handle `WM_NCPAINT` yourself. It is however something you are not supposed to do unless you are doing some very specific customization.